# Finding the memory position of mapping(address => uint) using JavaScript

Tags: web3js, storage, memory

I am wanting to read data from internal mappings with the following structures:

```
mapping (uint256 => uint256) internal nums;
mapping (address => uint256) internal addrToInt;
```

Finding the memory location of the `nums` data simply requires `uint256(keccak(a, b))`, where `a` is the starting location of the array, and `b` is the index into the array. In JavaScript we can  get this by:

```
w3.utils.hexToNumberString(w3.utils.soliditySha3(1, 2))
```

I am finding that this is not the case with the `addrToInt` mapping. If I run the following Python code:

```
w3.toInt(w3.soliditySha3(['address', 'uint256'], [addr, idx]))
```

then the key leads to an empty storage cell. The same incorrect key is also given with JavaScript:

```
w3.utils.hexToNumberString(w3.utils.soliditySha3({t: "address", v: addr}, {t: "uint256", v: idx}))
```

However, this Python code returns the correct key:

```
w3.toInt(w3.soliditySha3(['address[]', 'uint256[]'], [[addr], [idx]]))
```

What exactly is going on here by passing the variables as arrays into the function? And I am reading that we cannot pass array types into the web3js `soliditySha3` implementation, so is there any way to replicate the above Python code in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `uint256` for the key instead:

```
w3.utils.soliditySha3({t: 'uint256', v: addr}, {t: 'uint256', v:idx})
```

I believe that when computing storage slots, all values get padded to 32 bytes. Treating the address as a `uint256` left pads it with zeros.